# How to make sense of heartbeat in cassandra's nodetool's gossipinfo?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool, gossip

When I did nodetool gossipinfo on one of the nodes on cassandra server, I got the following output,

```
/192.168.0.36
  generation:1504926520
  heartbeat:2147483647
  DC:datacenter1
  STATUS:shutdown,true
  SEVERITY:0.0
  HOST_ID:0708fc6f-0423-46fc-8f56-8e7512a83de4
  LOAD:1.2352913099E10
  NET_VERSION:8
  RPC_ADDRESS:192.168.0.36
  RACK:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:2.1.6
  SCHEMA:04c4cc4f-7598-3e69-9455-8d8896b0624d
```

The gossip protocol on the cluster is not working properly and a lot of nodes are shown as DN.
I'm trying to make sense of heartbeat, which is 2147483647 (in future). Is this the cause of the failure of gossip protocol.

Thank you